# Running ls with wildcard string

Tags: bash

I was originally using this command, and it works fine (counting number of files with extension `.sb`):

`ls -dq *.sb | wc -l`

Output:

`903`

Now, I want to use a variable to store the string, like this:

`search="*.sb"`

Then, putting it all together:

```
# count files in directory with substring
search="*.sb"
ls -dq "$search" | wc -l
```

Output:

```
ls: cannot access *.sb: No such file or directory
0
```

This implies the string is being stored and retrieved correctly, but the command is not acting as expected. Could anyone explain this phenomenon to me?

Comment: Use an array, `search=(*.sb); printf '%s\n' "${#search[*]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable expansion is done before pathname expansion. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691956/how-to-make-bash-expand-wildcards-in-variables) for a similar situation.

Solution in this case: remove the quotation marks

```
search="*.sb"
ls -dq $search | wc -l
```

Comment: Huh, unexpected. OK, I use bash a fair bit but not for string manipulation, thank you! I'll accept your answer once the timer allows it.